# Complex MySQL Query for Many-to-Many

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have searched and gone through the available topics similar to mine. But, failed to find that satisfies my requirements. Hence, posting it here.

I have four tables as follows:

```
"Organization" table:
--------------------------------
| org_id       | org_name      |
| 1            | A             |
| 2            | B             |
| 3            | C             |

"Members" table:
----------------------------------------------
| mem_id       | mem_name     | org_id       |
| 1            | mem1         | 1            |
| 2            | mem2         | 1            |
| 3            | mem3         | 2            |
| 4            | mem4         | 3            |

"Resource" table:
--------------------------------
| res_id       | res_name      |
| 1            | resource1     |
| 2            | resource2     |
| 3            | resource3     |
| 4            | resource4     |

"member-resource" table:
--------------------------------------------
| sl_no        | mem_id     | res_id       |
| 1            | 1          | 1            |
| 2            | 1          | 2            |
| 3            | 2          | 1            |
| 4            | 4          | 3            |
| 5            | 3          | 4            |
| 6            | 2          | 3            |
| 7            | 4          | 3            |
```

I want to find out the total number of distinct resources according to organizations. Expected output is as follows:

```
| org_name       | Total Resources      |
| A              | 3                    |
| B              | 1                    |
| C              | 1                    |
```

I also want to find out the total number of shared resources according to organizations. Expected output is as follows:

```
| org_name       | Shared Resources     |
| A              | 1                    |
| B              | 0                    |
| C              | 1                    |
```

Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler than you think, particularly because you don't even need the `resource` table:

```
SELECT o.org_name, COUNT(DISTINCT mr.res_id) TotalResources
FROM member_resource mr
JOIN members m ON mr.mem_id = m.mem_id
JOIN organization o ON m.org_id = o.org_id
GROUP BY o.org_id
```

Output:

```
| ORG_NAME | TOTALRESOURCES |
|----------|----------------|
|        A |              3 |
|        B |              1 |
|        C |              1 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ccf83/1).

Comment: I want another help brother. How do i find the total resources according to organizations that are shared with other organizations. Expected output is: A > 1, B > 0, C > 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below.

```
SELECT org_name, COUNT(DISTINCT res_id)
FROM organization, members, member-resource
WHERE members.mem_id = member-resource.mem_id
AND organization.org_id = members.org_id
GROUP BY org_id, org_name
```